# Implementing smooth scrolling in react

Tags: reactjs, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to create a website for myself and when you click on an image the page will scroll down to another element in a different section.

The structure of my code now is that I have an App class and in that class I make two other components, call them A and B.

```
class App extends Component{
   render () { 
      return (<A/>
              <B/>)
}
```

The image the user clicks is in component A and the element I want to scroll to is in B. I've tried to do this using the `element.scrollIntoView` function by creating a ref like so:

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.divToFocus = React.createRef();
    }
    

    handleOnClick = () =>{
        this.divToFocus.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}
    }

    render () {
        return (
        <div>
            <A click={this.handleOnClick}/>
            <B name={this.divToFocus} />
        </div>)}
```

and in A using the `handleOnClick` for the img `onClick` attribute (making sure to set `"pointer-events": "all"` for style)and then creating a div with the ref named `this.divToFocus` in B but got a type error saying `this.divToFocus.scrollIntoView` is not a function.

I also tried using `react-scroll` by doing something like this:

```
class A extends Component{
    render (){ 
        return (
        <Element name={"name"}>
            Hello world!
        </Element>
    )}
}

class B extends Component{
    render (){ 
        return (
        <Link activeClass="active" to="name" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={50} duration={500}>
          <img src={arrow} />
        </Link>
    )}
}
```

but then nothing happened when I would click on the image. Any advice about how to do this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DOM and [ScrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to achieve this.

`A.js`

```
import React from "react";

export default function A() {
  const handleImageClick = () => {
    document.getElementById("myid").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  return (
      <img
        onClick={handleImageClick}
        alt="placeholder"
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x200.png?text=Visit+WhoIsHostingThis.com+Buyers+GuideC/O https://placeholder.com/"
      />
  );
}
```

`B.js`

```
import React from "react";

export default function B() {
  return (
    <div id="myid">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Some Long content for scroll to happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-haze-t6e3o?file=/src/B.js)